# How to add a new class to resumed vowpal wabbit one-against-all logistic classifier?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I have a working logistic regression classifier using the one-against-all (oaa) method. Although I'm currently training the classifier to recognize 15 classes, in the future I would like to feed it examples from N additional classes that I would like my classifier to learn. However, vowpal wabbit commands using the `--save_resume` option do not allow me to use `--oaa` to specify a new total number of classes.

I use the oaa option because when I make predictions I want to select the top 3 predicted classes that have the highest probability of being true, which I determine using the `--probabilities` option.

**How can I teach additional classes to my classifier when using `--oaa` and `--save_resume`?**

---

I initially train my classifier using:

`vw --oaa=15 --loss_function=logistic --save_resume -c --passes 10 -d /tmp/train.vw -f /tmp/model.vw`

I resume training using:

`vw --loss_function=logistic --save_resume -c --passes 10 -d /tmp/train.vw -i /tmp/model.vw -f /tmp/model.v`

I make predictions using:

`vw -t --probabilities --loss_function=logistic -d /tmp/test.vw -i /tmp/model.vw -p /tmp/predict.vw`

I then examine `predict.vw` and select the classes with the top 3 highest probabilities of being true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to increase the number N of classes in `--oaa N` when training in multiple steps with `--save_resume`. Internally, the model uses N for offsetting the weight vector, so you would need to hack the loading of the model.

You can try setting the N high enough from the beginning and using classes  1-15 in the first steps, and adding  classes with higher numbers in the later steps. Thanks to the nature of online training the later examples influence the model more.

Alternatively, with [csoaa_ldf](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~hal/tmp/multiclassVW.html) you can specify the number of classes on the fly: different classes may be *available* for each example.

Answer (score 0):

You may explore cb_explore_adf:

```
--cb_explore_adf
The contextual bandit learning algorithm for when the set of actions changes over time or you have rich information for each action.
```

from: https://vowpalwabbit.org/docs/vowpal_wabbit/python/latest/tutorials/python_Contextual_bandits_and_Vowpal_Wabbit.html?highlight=cb_explore_adf